# Make a variable a reference type

Tags: c#, .net, struct, moq

I have the following Mock in my C# test:

`private Mock<Offset> _mockOffsetPosition = new Mock<Offset>(50);`

`Offset` is a Confluent.Kafka.Offset struct.

it gives me this error:

> CS0452: The type 'Offset' must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Mock'

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why would you need to mock something that is a struct? Just use real thing. Most of the time you mock some interface which is too complex to use real type and you need only part of it.

Comment: Unless you can change the code of `Confluent.Kafka.Offset` you can't change it to a `class`. I'm not sure why you're mocking it though because it's a very simple object. I would just create a real one.

Comment: If you don´t know the difference between a value- and a reference-type you shouldn´t start by mocking interfaces. Sorry man

Comment: How to make a struct a reference type? simply just box it `(object)Offset`, However this is definitely an X/Y problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mock it. Lets see [what mocking is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object):

> In a unit test, mock objects can simulate the behavior of **complex**, **real objects** and are therefore useful **when a real object is impractical or impossible to incorporate**

So instead of mocking just initialize with the value you need and pass the real struct. This is should be the case for all value types.

```
private Offset _mockOffsetPosition = new Offset(50);
```